# A superclass method is called instead of the subclass method

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Let's take a look at this code:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void foo(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends ParentClass {
    public void foo(String s) {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ParentClass p = new SubClass();
        p.foo("hello");
    }
}
```

I expected this to print out "Child", but the result is "Parent". Why does java call the super class instead, and what do I do to make it call the method in the subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SubClass#foo()` does not override `ParentClass#foo()` because it doesn't have the same formal parameters. One takes `Object` and the other takes a `String`. Therefore polymorphism at runtime is not applied and does not cause the subclass method to execute. From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method `mC` declared in or inherited by class C, *overrides* from C another method `mA` declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>
> - A is a superclass of C.
> - C does not inherit `mA`.
> - **The signature of `mC` is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `mA`.**
>
> ...

And [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) defines method signatures:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the *same signature* if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method `m1` is a *subsignature* of the signature of a method `m2` if either:
>
> - `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
> - the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of `m2`.

Answer (score 1):

The parent class has no method with the signature `public void foo(String s)`. Therefore, at compile time, the compiler can only choose the `public void foo(Object o)` method for executing `p.foo("hello")`.

Since the child class doesn't override this method (it doesn't have the same parameter type), the parent class's `foo` method is the one executed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are objects in java, as said its not overridden but as you pass a string it will run the first available method that can the the argument, in this case it is the super-class's method.